# Меню внизу экрана

Tags: android

С помощью каких компонентов или библиотек лучше всего реализовать таб-меню внизу экрана ?

Пример:

[image: Меню внизу экрана]

И чтобы в будущем можно было без проблем добавить/удалить несколько пунктов меню.

Comment: это называется *Табы* (*Tabs*)

Comment: @metalurgus поправил на таб-меню)

Comment: Стоит заметить, что такие табы - гайдлайны айОС, а вовсе не андроид. Есть такое мнение, что при разработке нужно придерживаться гайдлайнов той операционной системы, под которую разрабатываешь, а всякая кустарщина не приветствуется.

Comment: @pavlofff, я в курсе, что гуглу такое не по душе. Гугл это нызавает "Pure android". Но нужно именно так..

Comment: только на одном SO примеров тьма.. https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=android+tabhost+bottom+screen